# Beginner: if else date

Tags: php

i'm an absolute beginner in php, and i'm just trying to make a simple if else statement. Please take a look at this:

```
<?php  
        $currentDate  = echo date("Y");
        $startup = '2013';
        if ($startup = $currentDate) {
      ?>
        &copy; 2013 Blue Box 22
      <?php } else { ?>
        &copy; 2013 - <?php echo date("Y"); ?> Blue Box 22
      <?php } ?>
```

As you can probably read, i'm just checking if the current year is equal to the startup year, and then let it display accordingly. I presume there's something wrong in my syntax as that part of my page isn't rendering.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `$currentDate  = echo date("Y");` no need for the `echo` there, that's probably the issue. Also, `=` is assigning, not comparing... use `==`

Comment: remove echo and use == instead of single one =

Comment: Thank you sourabh kasliwal, that was the correct answer. Maybe you should file it as a seperate answer so i can mark it as correct!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of:

```
if ($startup = $currentDate) {
```

it should be

```
if ($startup == $currentDate) {
```

Moreover, instead of using

```
$currentDate  = echo date("Y");
```

try:

```
$currentDate  = date("Y");
```

Answer (score 0):

You've assigned the variable in the `if` statement, not compared.  Comparisons are done with the `==` operator.

```
if ($startup == $currentDate) {

}
```

Which means if (startup is equal to the current date then do this)

Comment: what does `You need to add echo into the conditional statement.` mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  
        $currentDate  = date("Y");//echo removed, never use while comparison
        $startup = '2013';
        if ($startup == $currentDate) {// comparison is done by ==, = make assignment
      ?>
        &copy; 2013 Blue Box 22
      <?php } else { ?>
        &copy; 2013 - <?php echo date("Y"); ?> Blue Box 22
      <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This means assigning "="
This means comparing "=="

This should help you with your code. :)